# apply sum to data.frame grouped by substring, with R

Tags: r

Sample datas :

```
> mat1 = as.data.frame(matrix(c("D-J10-N1","D-J10-N2","D-J2-N1","D-J2-N2",3,6,5,7,8,4,2,3,4,1,2,3), ncol = 4));
> mat1
        V1 V2 V3 V4
1 D-J10-N1  3  8  4
2 D-J10-N2  6  4  1
3  D-J2-N1  5  2  2
4  D-J2-N2  7  3  3
```

desired output :

```
> results
        V1 V2 V3 V4
    1 J10  9  12  5
    2 J2   12 5   5
```

So I need to sum V2 to V4 by a substring of V1 and then return this substring in my results. I can define my groups as :

```
> groups <- substr(mat1[,1],1,5)
> groups
[1] "D-J10" "D-J10" "D-J2-" "D-J2-"
```

I thought using rowsum as in :

```
> rowsum(mat1,groups, reorder = TRUE)
```

But rowsum seems to accept only numerical values for groups ? I've looked in the apply family functions but found no luck.... Any ideas on how to solve that ?

Thank's a lot for helping !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to have the `data.frame` set up so the column classes fit a bit better (currently they are all factors).

```
mat1 <- data.frame(V1=c("D-J10-N1","D-J10-N2","D-J2-N1","D-J2-N2"),V2=c(3,6,5,7),V3=c(8,4,2,3),V4=c(4,1,2,3))
```

Then you can use `aggregate` and `sub` to pick out your substring:

```
aggregate(mat1[-1],by=list(sub("D-(J[0-9]+)-[A-Z0-9]+","\\1",mat1$V1)),sum)
  Group.1 V2 V3 V4
1     J10  9 12  5
2      J2 12  5  5
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Your code does what I need and I understand it. Now, trying to apply it to my actual dataset, I get an arguments must have same length error. length of my arguments fits. MOdified command :   > aggregate(table.off.fem, by=list(sub([D-F]-(J[0-9]+)-[A-Z0-9]+","\\1",rownames(table.off.fem))),sum). str(data) gives me int for numbers inside table. Why am I getting this error ?

Comment: > length(table.off.fem[,3])
[1] 136
> length(rownames(table.off.fem))
[1] 136. Data type is table, could this cause the error ? I can't juste simply data.frame my table....
> 
I realy don't get why I'm getting this arguments must have same length error.....

Comment: What is the result of `dim(as.data.frame(table.off.fem))`?

Comment: I guess something wrong with my cross table, why can't I data.frame it ? All rows from the original table (from which comes table.off.fem) are factors. Can't convert it to num though....Error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: @Chargaff Its to do with how `as.data.frame.table` works. Try `df.off.fem <- data.frame(apply(table.off.fem,2,list)); names(df.off.fem) <- colnames(table.off.fem)`

Comment: Yes, that works, thank you very much for helping. What exactly does that do ? Now I can convert this table to data.frame or pass the aggregate command.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets make your data a little differently.

```
mat1 <- data.frame(V1 = c("D-J10-N1","D-J10-N2","D-J2-N1","D-J2-N2"),
                   V2 = c(3,6,5,7),
                   V3 = c(8,4,2,3),
                   V4 = c(4,1,2,3))
```

If you look at `str` of your initial data, they're all characters.  Which is why rowsums erros.

Using `strsplit` and `lapply` gets you started:

```
mat1$new.V1 <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(mat1$V1, '-'), '[', 2))
```

However, depending on the data in the first column, you might want to use gsub and a regex:

```
gsub('.+-([0-z]+)-.+','\\1',mat1$V1)
```

or something like that...

Then I would look to the `plyr` package.

```
ddply(mat1, .(new.V1), summarise, sums = sum(V2, V3, V4))
```

Or as an ugly oneliner:

```
ddply(mat1, .(unlist(lapply(strsplit(mat1$V1, '-'), '[', 2))), summarise, sum(V2, V3, V4))
```

Comment: (+1) The one-liner is pretty cool. You will need to check that `options("stringsAsFactors")` is not set to `TRUE`, otherwise it will throw an error with `strsplit`.

Comment: @chl good point.  That's in my .Rprofile so I forget about the silly defaults.

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` package is good for this type of aggregation.  As others have said, I would reformat your data, like this:

```
library(data.table)
mat1 <- data.table(V1=c("D-J10-N1","D-J10-N2","D-J2-N1","D-J2-N2"),
                   V2=c(3,6,5,7),
                   V3=c(8,4,2,3),
                   V4=c(4,1,2,3),
                   key="V1")
```

Then you can sum it like this:

```
mat1[, lapply(.SD, sum), by=list(V1b=gsub(".*\\-(.*)\\-.*", "\\1", mat1[,V1]))]
#   V1b V2 V3 V4
#1: J10  9 12  5
#2:  J2 12  5  5
```

The `lapply(.SD, sum)` part is summing each column, and the `by` part is grouping it by the substring you requested (using `gsub` and a regular expression).